# How can I import many values to one foreign key value

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have an import script that imports from a csv file, but one value (customer) can repeat itself. So for example name will always be different, but customer (john) can have 5 entries. I need to import this into a foreign key named customer for other uses. But i dont know how to go about doing it.

My model

```
class Route_destinguisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rd = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='33763:264')
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

My Import code

```
dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in dataReader:
        route_distinguisher = Route_destinguisher()
        route_distinguisher.customer=row[2].split("-")[0]
        route_distinguisher.name=row[2]
        route_distinguisher.rd=row[1].replace('\t',':')
        route_distinguisher.save()
        print row
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a new model `Customer` with `name` field, `Route_destinguisher` model should have a foreign key to `Customer`:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Route_destinguisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rd = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='33763:264')
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Then, use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in the loop while importing csv:

```
dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in dataReader:
    route_distinguisher = Route_destinguisher()
    route_distinguisher.customer = Customer.objects.get_or_create(name=row[2].split("-")[0])
    route_distinguisher.name = row[2]
    route_distinguisher.rd = row[1].replace('\t',':')
    route_distinguisher.save()
    print row
```